# Pyramid security based on attribute of record

Tags: python, pyramid

I have tables in DB with the same interface for view and edit them with Pyramid app. For example:

Example of route for view record of `report` table: `/birdreport/report/871`;

Example of route for edit record of `report` table: `/birdreport/report/871/edit`;

Each record of `report` table has field which contains `user_id` - this value is the same as returned by authenticated_userid function. It is clear for me how I can disable acces to `edit` by adding permission to view. But how I can enable access to `edit` view only for those users which userid presents in corresponding record?

Comment: Probably it is necessary to add route configuration to the question, because the behavior in this case depends on whether you are using `url dispatch` or `traversal`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [Pyramid authorization policy](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/security.html) by defining `__acl__()` inside your `Report` model. For example:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from pyramid.security import Everyone, Allow

class Report(Base):
    # ...
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    # ...


    @property
    def __acl__(self):
        return [
            (Allow, Everyone, 'view'),
            (Allow, self.user_id, 'edit'),
        ]

    # this also works:
    #__acl__ = [
    #    (Allow, Everyone, 'view'),
    #    (Allow, self.user_id, 'edit'),
    #]

class User(Base):
    # ...
    reports = relationship('Report', backref='user')
```

The `__acl__()` above will allow everyone to call your view `view`, but only the user related to `Report` to `edit` it.

---

It's likely that you haven't had authentication policy or authorization policy enabled, to quote the [documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/security.html#enabling-an-authorization-policy-imperatively):

> Use the set_authorization_policy() method of the Configurator to enable an authorization policy.
>
> You must also enable an authentication policy in order to enable the authorization policy. This is because authorization, in general, depends upon authentication. Use the set_authentication_policy() and method during application setup to specify the authentication policy.

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.authentication import AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy
from pyramid.authorization import ACLAuthorizationPolicy
authentication_policy = AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy('seekrit')
authorization_policy = ACLAuthorizationPolicy()
config = Configurator()
config.set_authentication_policy(authentication_policy)
config.set_authorization_policy(authorization_policy)
```

> The above configuration enables a policy which compares the value of an “auth ticket” cookie passed in the request’s environment which contains a reference to a single principal against the principals present in any ACL found in the resource tree when attempting to call some view.
>
> While it is possible to mix and match different authentication and authorization policies, it is an error to configure a Pyramid application with an authentication policy but without the authorization policy or vice versa. If you do this, you’ll receive an error at application startup time.

Comment: Thanks for response. I've solved my problem using [Simple Object-Level Authorization](http://michael.merickel.org/projects/pyramid_auth_demo/group_security.html#simple-object-level-authorization) approach proposed by Michael Merickel.